# How to make the "hot area" of a UIControl bigger?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicontrol

Or: How to expand the sensitive area for a UIControl without just making the view bigger?

I have a pretty small button image (a little arrow), which is just 10 x 10 pixels. Too small for touching. I want the "hot area" to be 50 x 50 around that. For learning, I want to know how to do it manually, even if I could use some of the provided UIControls for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always layer another view over top -- perhaps a UIButton set to custom type so it's invisible -- and have that button trigger what you want to happen when it gets touched.

But your *real* issue is using 10x10 pixel areas for user control in the first place. The smallest user control I can think of (say, in the Calendar app) has about a 30x30 area for the [+] button.

Think of your users and ask yourself what their experience will be dealing with tiny little controls.